# cannot convert FILE* -C++

Tags: c++, file-io

I've been asked to make a program for my university course and it needs to check how many open and closed brackets are in a file. I am getting two error messages for my function:

> 40:22: cannot convert FILE* {aka_IO_FILE*} to 'const char*' for argument '1' FILE*
>   fpin = fopen(fpin);
>   42:22: warning format '%s' expects argument of type 'char*', but argument 2 has type 'int'
>   printf("Could not open %s \n", arr[1]);

```
void countBrackets(char arr[])
{
    int bracketCount = 0:
    int lineNumber = 0;
    //tracking position in file 
    FILE* fpin;
    //open file and check to make sure 
    //file opened safley
    fpin = fopen(fpin);
    if (fpin == NULL){
        printf("Could not open %s \n", arr[1]);
        return;
    }
    //Count how many opened and closed { and } brackets are 
    //in the file
    for ( char currCh = 0; currCh > lineNumber; currCh ++){
        if (currCh == '{') {
            bracketCount ++;
        }else if (currCh == '}') {
            bracketCount ++;
        }else (currCh == '\n') {
            lineNumber ++;
        }
        //display error messages for the user
        if (bracketCount < 0) {
            printf("there is more closing brackets than opening\n");
        }else{
            printf("There is more opening brackets than closing\n");
        }
    }
    fclose(fpin);
}
```

Comment: Read the description of the `fopen()` library function. Its first parameter must be a `const char *`. Since `arr` is an array, `arr[1]` is a `char`, and the `%s` format specification requires a `const char *` value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the argument `fpin` here with the file you want to open. Which you probably want to be `arr`. You'll also need to pass a mode argument. Just `"r"` would be appropriate here.

```
fpin = fopen(fpin);
```

Replace `arr[1]` with just `arr`. `arr[1]` would be the second character of `arr` and not the string %s requires.

```
printf("Could not open %s \n", arr[1]);
```

This should be enough for it to compile..

Comment: This answer doesn't address many of the problems with the OP's code